# scm setup for copying project from windows to ubuntu using capistrano

Tags: capistrano3, rvm-capistrano, whenever-capistrano

I want to deploy my sample project from ubuntu to windows I have succesfully make a ssh key on ubuntu. Now I want to do this via only copying files from the windows to the ubuntu remotely. When I execute 'cap production deploy', I got this error
'fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.'
I guest this is from the git.
my question is, How can setup inscm if I had only copy and paste the project from windows to server?

by the way this are the codes of my follwing rb files:

*Deployer.rb*

`lock '3.5.0'
--set :application, 'my_app_name'
--set :repo_url, 'git@example.com:me/my_repo.git'
set   :application,   "zemsoft"
--set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/my-app.com"
set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/e"
set   :domain,        "zemsofterp2.com"`

set     :scm,          "git"
--set   :repository,    "file:///   Users/deployer/sites/my-app"
set   :repository,     "C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor"
set   :deploy_via,    :copy
set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3
-- Default branch is :master
-- ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

-- Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
-- set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'

-- Default value for :scm is :git
-- set :scm, :git

-- Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
-- set :format, :airbrussh

-- You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
-- These are the defaults.
-- set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: 'log/capistrano.log', color: :auto, truncate: :auto

-- Default value for :pty is false
-- set :pty, true

-- Default value for :linked_files is []
-- set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

-- Default value for linked_dirs is []
-- set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system')

-- Default value for default_env is {}
-- set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

-- Default value for keep_releases is 5
-- set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      -- Here we can do anything such as:
      -- within release_path do
       --  execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
       end
    end
  end

end

*Production.rb*

role :app, %w{ely029@192.168.1.241} # EDIT your ssh username and server ip address

set :ssh_options, {
    auth_methods: %w(password),
    password: "embuscado29" # EDIT your ssh password

Answer (score 1):

`set :deploy_via, :copy` does nothing; this is not a valid Capistrano 3 setting.

Capistrano 3 has no built-in mechanism for deploying by way of copying files from one machine to another. You need a central source code repository, such as a remote Git repository that the server can access.

There are third-party Capistrano plugins that may provide the copying behavior you need (search GitHub for [capistrano copy](https://github.com/search?q=capistrano%20copy&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1)), but I cannot vouch for their quality or effectiveness. My recommendation would be to use a remote Git repository.